# bootstrap table css / database

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the code below to gather and show the data stored in a database. Everything is workig fine but I am not able to show it with bootstrap css. If I copy an exemple of a table (code 2 below) in boostrap it does work (which means I did included all the files for bootstrap correctly).
Is there something i am missing? WHy the table I retrieve show up as a plain table and not with bootstrap css that looks nicer?

-------code 1------------

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ..."; 
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<table>"; 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   
echo "<tr><td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>
               <td>" . $row['...'] . "</td>
               <td>" . $row['...'] . "</td>
               <td>" . $row['...'] . "</td>
               <td>" . $row['...'] . "</td>
               <td>" . $row['...'] . "</td>
               </tr>";
}echo "</table>";
 mysql_close(); //Make sure to close out the database connection
?>
```

-----------code 2-----------

```
<div class="bs-example">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Row</th>
                <th>Bill</th>
                <th>Payment Date</th>
                <th>Payment Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="active">
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Credit Card</td>
                <td>04/07/2014</td>
                <td>Call in to confirm</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="danger">
                <td>5</td>
                <td>Telephone</td>
                <td>06/07/2014</td>
                <td>Due</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

-----------exemple solution updated--------

```
    echo "<table class='table'>";
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr class='info'><td>" . $row['...'] . "</td>
                   <td>" . $row['...'] . "</td>
                   <td>" . $row['...'] . "</td>
                   <td>" . $row['...'] . "</td>
                   <td>" . $row['...'] . "</td>
                   <td>" . $row['...'] . "</td>
                   </tr>"; 
    }
    echo "</table>"; 
    mysql_close(); 

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the table class:

```
echo "<table class='table'>";
```

Comment: Thank you, I was actually writing: <table class="table">

Comment: It should work with double-quotes too, but then you need to escape the quotes. Example: `echo "<table class=\"table\">";`

Answer (score 1):

The magic of bootstrap is in its class attributes. You need to add the specific bootstrap class attributes that you want to help structure your table. Like `table`, `active` and `danger`. As you can see quite clearly the difference in code 1 and code 2 are the class attributes. Give [this](http://tomasjanecek.cz/en/clanky/post/list-of-bootstrap-3-css-classes-with-description) blog post a read to get more info on what each attribute does for you.